# Unable to autowired DAO in Spring boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, repository, autowired

I have my application in **in.orgname.projectname.backend**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Dao in **in.orgname.projectname.backend.model.dao**

```
public interface MyUserDao extends CrudRepository<MyUser, String>{

    public MyUser findByEmailId(String emailId);
}
```

My entity lies in **in.orgname.projectname.backend.model.entity**

and finally trying to access this DAO in my Controller which is in **in.orgname.projectname.backend.controllers**

```
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    MyUserDao myUserDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> authenticate(@RequestParam(value = "authcode") String authCode){

        //Some other code
    }

}
```

I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: in.orgname.projectname.backend.model.dao.MyUserDao in.orgname.projectname.backend.controllers.AuthenticationController.myUserDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [in.orgname.projectname.backend.model.dao.MyUserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at in.orgname.projectname.backend.Application.main(Application.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: in.orgname.projectname.backend.model.dao.MyUserDao in.orgname.projectname.backend.controllers.AuthenticationController.myUserDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [in.orgname.projectname.backend.model.dao.MyUserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [in.orgname.projectname.backend.model.dao.MyUserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

I have been through various sources on StackOverflow but none seem to have solved my problem.

How do I handle this?

**EDIT1:** I have also tried `@Component` directly on the DAO class.

**EDIT2:** Here is the git repository to the project which has the same error - https://github.com/amitection/myuser-poc

Comment: There is an extra **i** in `iin.orgname.projectname.backend.controllers.AuthenticationController.myUserDao;`. Not sure if it's related to the problem

Comment: I'll edit that. That's just because I have changed the package names cause I can't expose the project name.

Comment: I created a new project, copied your code, invented my own `MyUser` entity and I'm unable to reproduce your issue. Either the packages you posted are wrong, are you are using different imports (perhaps `CrudRepository` is not Spring data's interface?). If you can't post a proper MVCE I'm afraid we can't help.

Comment: @g00glen00b I have added the src for the project. Please check the update part(EDIT 2].

Comment: I was just browsing through my earlier POCs which had worked perfectly fine earlier (which I had developed on another machine) and now even those give the same error on my machine. I know it sounds silly but could this be a system related issue? :|

Comment: We need more context around the startup sequence. Can you share the full startup log?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample application the problem is you don't have the postgresql library as a dependency. Without that Spring won't autoconfig a Repository bean backed by postgres.

You will want to add:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Spring Boot Autoconfiguration only loads beans when it detects specific classes on the classpath. Once it sees postgresql on the classpath then it will try to generate the Repository bean.

Comment: I suppose that's altogether a different issue. Exceptions thrown in that case are different. Even if I add dependency the problem persists. Like I mentioned in the 5th comment under the question it is some weird OS specific issue. I know it sounds silly. Cause the same code when I try to run in Windows works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup scanning `<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />` in servlet.xml to do automatic referencing or add `@ComponentScan` to Application class in Spring Boot.

Comment: Annotation `@SpringBootApplication` should already do the `@ComponentScan`

Comment: @CarlosRivero True. Explicit **ComponentScan** with package name is needed when the other packages are not a sub package of the package in which the Application class lies

Comment: in.orgname.projectname.backend.model.dao is subpackage of  in.orgname.projectname.backend so it will be scanned automatically

Answer (score 0):

1. add this dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

2. then add `@MapperScan` to the starter class